# How to pass Server Sent Event object in setInterval(function(){...})

Tags: javascript, setinterval, server-sent-events

I want to stop SSE after some interval and need to reconnect again.

Using `setInterval(function(){})` in JavaScript gives error:

```
source.close(); // <<-- ERROR : object is not defined
```

Can anyone guide me for solution please?

```
<script>

if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined"){

    var source = new EventSource("sse_server.php");

    // ReConnecting ST
    setInterval(function(){ 
        console.log("ReConnecting...");

        source.close(); // <<---------- ERROR : object is not defined

        var source = new EventSource("sse_server.php");
    }, 6000); 
    // ReConnecting EN

    source.addEventListener("response", function(event) {
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p>" + event.data + "</p>";
    });

    source.addEventListener("message_status", function(event) {
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p>" + event.data + "</p>";
    });

    source.onmessage = function(event) {

        var json = JSON.parse(event.data);

        if(json.category=="chat") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p>"  + json.content.messageContent.messageText + "</p>";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p>" + event.data + "</p>";
        } 

  };

} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}


</script>
```

Comment: remove `var ` from `var source = new EventSource("sse_server.php");`. Variables are hoisted in JS

Comment: Thanks for your help

But this way it stops showing output from SSE
http://prntscr.com/n3lfwy

http://prntscr.com/n3lhcp

Comment: BTW, SSE auto-connects if the connection is lost. You shouldn't need to reconnect every 6 seconds (unless you are deliberately stress-testing a server).
You *might* want to use keep-alive, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21846325/841830   Incidentally, that answer also shows how to structure what you are trying to do, by wrapping your `new EventSource()` call in a function :-)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

> ```
> source.close(); // <<---------- ERROR : object is not defined
> var source = new EventSource("sse_server.php");
> ```

You've defined a **different** variable with the **same name** in the scope of your function. Since you don't assign a value to it until the next line, it is `undefined`.

If you want to access the `source` from the wider scope inside the function, then don't reuse the name for a different variable inside the function.

If you want to *overwrite* the `source` in the wider variable, then remove `var` from the line inside the function so you use the existing variable and don't redeclare it in the local scope.

Comment: Thanks for your help

But this way it stops showing output from SSE
http://prntscr.com/n3lfwy

http://prntscr.com/n3lhcp

Comment: @Viral — You have a new source … and you haven't attached your event listeners to the new one.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do that ?

Basically, I want to use one source object but want to close and reconnect after some time.

Comment: Err. Look at your code. See the line `source.addEventListener("response", function(event) {`? And see the line `};` (just before the `else`)? And everything between them? Do that.

Comment: thanks @Quentin. I looked at where you pointed. it looks fine to me. 
I even tested it , When i remove setInterval everyting works fine. 

But with that its not showing output.

Comment: @Viral — It is fine … for the object you assign to `source` on line 5. When you assign a new object on line 13 you don't attach event listeners to it.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. for that i have reasign new event source after closing it.
see this. I have create new one again. Plz see this https://prntscr.com/n3lr7p

can you plz guide me with sample code you are talking about ?

Comment: You already have sample code in your question. You just just to call it at the right time.

Comment: can you guide me, What change do i have to do in that code ? I removed "var" as suggested. I am closing connection and re-assigning to same variable. what goes wrong ? You said call it at right time -> what exactly need to change in code ?

Comment: Take a piece of paper. Pin it to the wall. Write on it "response", "message_status", and "onmessage". Then take a new piece of paper. Replace the old piece of paper with it. Tear the old piece of paper up and put it in the bin. This is what you have done. Look at how you put  "response", "message_status", and "onmessage" on the last piece of paper.